# Calling function inside a button for unit test

Tags: c#, forms, function, unit-testing, button

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtFirstName.Text.Trim() != "" && txtLastName.Text.Trim() != "" && txtContact.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"); //only accepting proper email
            Match match = reg.Match(txtEmail.Text.Trim());
            if (match.Success)
            { using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) // connecting info to database
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ContactAddorEdit", sqlCon);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneBookID", PhoneBookID); //connecting each value to database
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtContact.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // executeing the query in database
                    MessageBox.Show("Submitted successfully"); // showing message when success
                    Clear(); // clearing the form
                    GridFill();// refreshing the table
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Please enter a valid Email"); // Showing MEssage when email is not valid
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill Mandatory fields"); // if no input this message will show
        }
```

These codes are under a "save" button in a form and i wanted to call them in the unit test class in order to test them out. Any idea what should i do? Thank you

Comment: Move the testable code into a class you can test and call that class from the button click event. This is good practice anyway, DB code should never be in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, congratulations on trying to figure out how to write unit tests. Isolating code into testable units is a habit that leads to all sorts of great patterns.

There's a lot of ideas about how we might set something like this up, but all I'm going to put here are some steps in the direction of isolating code for testing without changing the code itself very much.

I wouldn't stop with this - in fact, in a short time after reading and learning more you'll probably pick up some even better techniques. I feel the need to point that out because what I'm describing here is a step, not a final destination.

First, you could move your SQL code to a class like this:

```
public class SqlCommands
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public SqlCommands(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public void InsertUpdateContact(InsertUpdateContactParameters parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) 
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ContactAddorEdit", sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneBookID", parameters.PhoneBookId); //connecting each value to database
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName",parameters.FirstName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName",parameters.LastName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact",parameters.Contact);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", parameters.Email);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address",parameters.Address);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

public class InsertUpdateContactParameters
{
    public int PhoneBookId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

As a first step you could create an instance of the `SqlCommands` class in your form, and then call `InsertUpdateContact`, passing in parameters populated from your form fields. That gets you to a point where you can create tests for your SQL code that you can execute without actually having to open your form, type in values, and press a button.

The test for your SQL code isn't technically a unit test because it talks to your database. It's an integration test. But it looks and functions just like a unit test. You're going to

- Arrange - set something up
- Act - execute your method
- Assert - your test passes if the thing you expect happens, otherwise it fails.

For a real simple test, you could

- Arrange - delete all records from your table that match some pattern, like the email address is "integrationtest@integrationtest.com" or the like.
- Act - Call your method, passing in a set of values including the same email address that you just deleted.
- Assert - Query your database to confirm that it contains a record matching the values you just inserted.
- Cleanup - for good measure, run the delete again so you don't leave the testing record behind.

To make the inserts and deletions easier you could put a class in your unit test project something like this:

```
static class Sql
{
    public static void ExecuteSql(string connectionName, string sql)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(connectionName)))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public static T ExecuteScalar<T>(string connectionName, string sql)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(connectionName)))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                return (T)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetConnectionString(string connectionName)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

If you're using the .NET Framework, you could have an app.config file with a connection strings section like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="yourDatabaseName" connectionString="whatever your connection string is" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Or you could code it to retrieve your connection string according to however you're storing it.

That allows you to write code in your tests like

```
Sql.ExecuteSql("Your connection name", "SQL to delete records");
```

or

```
var numberOfInsertedRecords = Sql.ExecuteScalar<int>("Your connection name",
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Whatever WHERE ... " 
    + "Replace with criteria that checks for the record you just inserted."
```

Then in your test you can say:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, numberOfInsertedRecords);
```

Some other interesting areas you might like to read about are dependency injection, ORMs (like Entity Framework and NHibernate), and CQRS. That's a whole lot of stuff to pile on, but if you're just starting off writing a form and some SQL and you're already thinking about unit tests then the sky's the limit.

---

[Here's a blog post](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/19/testing-data-access-and-stored-procedures.html) I wrote about this a few years ago. It feels dated. I feel compelled to apologize for just about anything I've written more than a year or two ago.